# after untracking I can see modified files

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a repo and it has some folders that are not in the development phase, so I want them to exist in my local repo and in remote also.

I just don't want to push/pull them.

So, I want to untrack those folders (and subfolders) ( but keep them in my repo and in remote ).

So , I added to .gitignore:

```
/thefolder/*
```

and run:

```
git ls-files -z ~/project/thefolder/ | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

but after commiting and pushing I can see modified files in this folder when running `git status`

Comment: @Deb:If you see in the duplicate I am  using the second's answer solution ( which is prefered as I saw from other posts ) and still have this problem.So,can you remove the duplicate?Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding thefolder/* without leading / ?

Comment: @Deb:I have also other 2 folders (with the same way /thefolder/* ) and I don't have a problem with them.Only with this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete it so that git knows that they have been deleted.

1. Store a copy of your folder somewhere.
2. Do a `git rm -fr <your folder>`
3. Commit the changes
4. Add the folder again

Now it will work as expected

Comment: :If I have to delete them , then what is the purpose of using `update-index` and adding to `.gitignore`?Is this the only way?And after commiting do I have to push also?

Comment: I think there should be a way to update the `index` without deleting and moving the files back but I am yet to find it :). But this approach works. I will try to find a better approach and update the response.

Comment: And yes you need to push the changes too